# Font won't load on server

Tags: html, css, fonts, cpanel

A specific font with format .ttf is not loading on the webserver. Its an adobe font called Edwardian Script that ive been using from the adobe typekit.

I have tried to load this font on the live website but it doesn't seem to want to load.

I have tried changing file paths, i have added the format("truetype") as suggested answer in another SO Question but this didn't work either.

I had thought about loading it from google fonts but it costs money here and we already have this font in our libraries.

Ive been emptying caches and retrying on a separate computer.

I might note that it does show in Dreamweaver so I've been using a separate computer to confirm if its corrected.

I feel its a file path issue but i don't seem to be getting the right path.

Its hosted with cPanel in a public_html folder within a folder called fonts

public_html > fonts > Edwardian-Script > Edwardian-Script-ITC.ttf

CSS

```
@font-face {
 font-family: Edwardian Script ITC;
 src: url('/fonts/Edwardian-Script/Edwardian-Script-ITC.ttf')        format("truetype"); 
}

.logo-text {
font-family: Edwardian Script ITC;
text-transform: none;
font-weight: 100; 
font-kerning: none;
font-stretch: normal;
letter-spacing: normal; 
}
```

HTML

```
<h3 class="logo-text"> Header Title </h3>
```

Expected to see loaded font from the server fonts folder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add MIME Types on your server.

1. Log in to cPanel.
2. In the ADVANCED section of the cPanel home screen, click MIME Types

Comment: Hey, have tried this, the .ttf was not added and have added it to cPanel but on cache clear and refresh, nothing changes on site. 

I have also tried direct file path in css which I did not try, to the server hosted file via http://website.com/fonts/edwardian...etc along side this.